# JQUERY: Creating Custom function using $(this)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Around a year ago I made a questionnaire that was a single page site with multiple divs serving as pages which I toggled on and off with buttons.  At the time I didn't know as much as I do now so I coded JQUEry for each button which goes as follows.

```
$("#start_btn").click(function(){
  $("#welcome").css("display","none");
  $("#page01").fadeIn('slow');
  $("#MainPage").css("background","rgba(255, 255, 255, .44)");
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$("#p1_next").click(function(){
  $("#page01").css("display","none");
  $("#page02").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$("#p2_back").click(function(){
  $("#page02").css("display","none");
  $("#page01").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
$("#p2_next").click(function(){
  $("#page02").css("display","none");
  $("#page03").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$("#p3_back").click(function(){
  $("#page03").css("display","none");
  $("#page02").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
$("#p3_next").click(function(){
  $("#page03").css("display","none");
  $("#page04").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$("#p4_back").click(function(){
  $("#page04").css("display","none");
  $("#page03").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
$("#p4_next").click(function(){
  $("#page04").css("display","none");
  $("#page05").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$("#p5_back").click(function(){
  $("#page05").css("display","none");
  $("#page04").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
$("#p5_next").click(function(){
  $("#page05").css("display","none");
  $("#page06").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$("#p6_back").click(function(){
  $("#page06").css("display","none");
  $("#page05").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
$("#p6_next").click(function(){
  $("#page06").css("display","none");
  $("#page07").fadeIn('slow');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
```

And that goes on for 24 more pages 2 buttons each page.  Now that I know a little more I'm attempting to achieve that same thing by doing this.

```
function Page_Turn(){

    var turn = $(this).data("turn_to");

        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            $(turn).css("display", "block");
        })  
}
```

Here's the HTML I'm trying to trigger it with.

```
<div id="Test_Page_02" class="content_section text_section_a Page color_style_b_1">
        PAGE 02

        <div class="button_normal button_right color_style_b_1" data-turn_to="#Test_Page_01" onclick="Page_Turn()">
            PREVIOUS
        </div>

        <div class="button_normal button_right color_style_b_1" data-turn_to="#Test_Page_03" onclick="Page_Turn()">
            NEXT
        </div>

    </div>
```

the relevant CSS for the functionality is this

```
.Page{
    height: 44em;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0.33em;
    position: relative;
}

#Test_Page_01{
    display: block;
}

#Test_Page_02{
    display: none;
}

#Test_Page_03{
    display: none;
}

#Test_Page_04{
    display: none;
}
```

So far I haven't been able to get it to work.  I originally started off using

```
$(this).attr("data-turn_to");
```

in the var, I also wrapped it in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

and was trying to make it a custom function with

```
$.fn.PageTurn = function(){
            var turn = $(this).attr("data-turn_to");

            $(this).onclick(function(){
                $(this).css("display", "none");
                $(turn).css("display", "block");
            });

        }
```

Which in that example I was using

```
.onclick()
```

which I changed to

```
.click()
```

Nothing I do seems to be working, I don't see any errors in the console, I'm lost.  here's a fiddle of what I have so far including the rest of the css elements.  https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/evz2r8h4/1/

Comment: can i make a new one , to make you understand easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jquery you don't need to call a defined function in the html. Instead you could do something like:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evz2r8h4/3/)

```
$('[data-turn_to]').on('click', function() {
  var turn = $(this).attr("data-turn_to");
  $(this).parent().css("display", "none"); // hide the parent (not just the clicked element)
  $(turn).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: nice , short and clean :D

Comment: sorry thought I checked this the other day as the answer.  But this worked out great, I even added animations to it lol

Answer (score 1):

If i understood right, you can do this with a simple code

1. Add a common class and a unique id to all page div's.
2. A common div to all click button's with a data attribute something like data-turn-to=""
3. Use the following code:

   ```
   $('.common-div-class').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('data-turn-on');
     $('.common-div-class').hide();
     $('#' + id).show();
   })
   ```